# Adding a row between cell with the same value using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Im new in VBA and want to know how can i format my table in such a way that each name in Column one do only have 1 row in between.

Some of them do have more than 1 row in between and some of them doesn't have. I just need to format then in such a way where every name on column A has 1 blank row in between. Any help would be appreciated!

Please note that i have thousands of data so manual will not work.

also i tried doing the filtering and convert them into single block. the problem with single block is that my column **c** do have more than 1 information which is connected to column **a**, .
here is an example.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUQjX.png)

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far? As a new user, you might benefit from looking at some tips on how to ask questions, and have the best hope of getting great answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd start by sorting. That will pull all the info into a single block. Then just look up how to loop through a range and (starting at the bottom, using `Step -1`) go up the rows and insert a new row when the current row's cell doesn't equal the one above.

Comment: i tried sorting and filtering.